# Android overrideable style elements in a library

Tags: android, android-library, android-styles

I am trying to make a library for a project and for the same I need to make some default styles for TextView, etc, and allow the application to be able to override the styles.

Following how it's done in a few open source projects, I have done this:

Library/values/attrs.xml

```
<resources>
        <attr name="customTextView" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="customEditText" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Library/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="customTextView">@style/tv</item>
    <item name="customEditText">@style/et</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">?attr/customEditText</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">?attr/customTextView</item>
</style>
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Error:(5, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'customEditText'.
```

Not sure what I've missed. Can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on what is going wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the custom xmlns at the root node of the style resources file ?